# If statement in SQL Server trigger isn't working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have created this table:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id =OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[czlonkowie_jednostek]') AND type IN (N'U'))
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[czlonkowie_jednostek]
    (
            [id_czlonkostwa] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            [id_uzytkownika] [int] NOT NULL,
            [id_jednostki] [int] NOT NULL,
            [data_od_przynaleznosci] [date],
            [data_do_przynaleznosci] [date]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
END
```

where id_uzytkownika and id_jednostki are foreign keys.

Also there is trigger which is responsible for checking if the newly inserted id_uzytkownika is not does not coincide with times for earlier records for this id_uzytkownika:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.triggers 
           WHERE Name = 'PilnujCzlonkowJednostki')
    DROP TRIGGER PilnujCzlonkowJednostki
GO

CREATE TRIGGER PilnujCzlonkowJednostki 
ON [dbo].[czlonkowie_jednostek]
FOR INSERT
AS
DECLARE @wstawiany_poczatek date
DECLARE @wstawiany_koniec date
DECLARE @wstawiany_czlonek int
DECLARE @ile int

-- czy tylko 1 czlonkostwo
SELECT @ile = COUNT(*) FROM inserted

IF @ile > 1
BEGIN
    raiserror ('wstawienie wiecej niz jednego czlonka jednoczesnie zabronione - anulowano!',16,1)
    rollback
    return
END

SELECT 
    @wstawiany_czlonek = id_uzytkownika,
    @wstawiany_poczatek = data_od_przynaleznosci,
    @wstawiany_koniec = data_do_przynaleznosci  
FROM 
    inserted

--przeglad istniejacych wpisow
DECLARE @czlonek_baza int
DECLARE @poczatek_baza date
DECLARE @koniec_baza date

DECLARE kursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT id_uzytkownika, data_od_przynaleznosci,data_do_przynaleznosci
    FROM czlonkowie_jednostek

OPEN kursor

FETCH NEXT FROM kursor
INTO @czlonek_baza, @poczatek_baza, @koniec_baza;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF ((@wstawiany_czlonek = @czlonek_baza AND (@wstawiany_poczatek between @poczatek_baza and @koniec_baza))
    OR
    (@wstawiany_czlonek = @czlonek_baza AND (@wstawiany_koniec between @poczatek_baza and @koniec_baza))
    OR
    (@wstawiany_czlonek = @czlonek_baza AND (@wstawiany_poczatek <= @poczatek_baza and @wstawiany_koniec >= @koniec_baza)))
    BEGIN
    raiserror('Wstawiany czlonek jest czlonkiem innej jednostki w tym samym czasie!',16,1)
    rollback
    CLOSE kursor
    DEALLOCATE kursor
    return
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM kursor
    INTO @czlonek_baza, @poczatek_baza, @koniec_baza;
END

CLOSE kursor
DEALLOCATE kursor
GO
```

During executing trigger script everything looks fine. Unfortunately when I'm trying to instert records to TABLE [dbo].[czlonkowie_jednostek], trigger appears to execute IF statement despite the table is empty.

Code I am trying to insert:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[czlonkowie_jednostek] ([id_uzytkownika],[id_jednostki],[data_od_przynaleznosci],[data_do_przynaleznosci])
VALUES(13,2,'1997-09-01','2000-08-31')
```

Response from the server I am getting:

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure PilnujCzlonkowJednostki, Line 257
>   Wstawiany czlonek jest czlonkiem innej jednostki w tym samym czasie!
>   Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 213
>   The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Can you see what am I missing?

Comment: Don't `@wstawiany_czlonek = @czlonek_baza AND (@wstawiany_poczatek between @poczatek_baza and @koniec_baza)` and `@wstawiany_czlonek = @czlonek_baza AND (@wstawiany_poczatek <= @poczatek_baza and @wstawiany_koniec >= @koniec_baza)` perform the same logic except that the range check is reversed? Try cleaning up the logic by factoring out `@wstawiany_czlonek = @czlonek_baza` and seeing what's left. Then get rid of the cursor and use a set-based query with `exists` to check for violations of your business rule. Then remove the restriction on single row `insert` and add support for `update`.

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account! Make it a **set-based** trigger, and do everything to **AVOID** cursors inside a trigger!

Comment: @marc_s The trigger explicitly checks the number of rows in `inserted` and uses `RaIsError` and `Rollback` if more than one row is found. While it isn't ideal by any means, it may have been a requirement that single rows be processed and rejected rather than a batch. (It certainly makes it easier to determine which row caused a violation of the business rule.) No, a cursor isn't needed. Yes, a set-based solution is preferable. And often an `insert` trigger for an odd business rule implies that `update` should also be checked. But the OP did not assume a single row per firing.

Comment: @HABO
`@wstawiany_czlonek = @czlonek_baza AND (@wstawiany_poczatek <= @poczatek_baza and @wstawiany_koniec >= @koniec_baza)` extends rather than reverses previous condition. Anyway, accordingly to your advices and Aleksei Lychev answer I have used set-based query. Also I have left the restriction of a single record `insert`. Now trigger works as it should. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger fires after the insert performed, so when you're looping through dbo.czlonkowie_jednostek records, the row you're trying to insert is processed too.
So I'd go with something like this (removing CURSOR too):

```
ALTER TRIGGER PilnujCzlonkowJednostki 
ON [dbo].[czlonkowie_jednostek]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @inserted_id_czlonkostwa INT
    SELECT @inserted_id_czlonkostwa = IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.czlonkowie_jednostek')

    DECLARE @wstawiany_poczatek date
    DECLARE @wstawiany_koniec date
    DECLARE @wstawiany_czlonek int
    DECLARE @ile INT

    -- czy tylko 1 czlonkostwo
    SELECT @ile = COUNT(*) FROM inserted

    IF @ile > 1
    BEGIN
        raiserror ('wstawienie wiecej niz jednego czlonka jednoczesnie zabronione - anulowano!',16,1)
        rollback
        return
    END

    SELECT 
        @wstawiany_czlonek = id_uzytkownika,
        @wstawiany_poczatek = data_od_przynaleznosci,
        @wstawiany_koniec = data_do_przynaleznosci  
    FROM 
        INSERTED

    PRINT @inserted_id_czlonkostwa

    IF EXISTS(SELECT *
        FROM czlonkowie_jednostek cj
        WHERE ((@wstawiany_czlonek = cj.id_uzytkownika AND (@wstawiany_poczatek between cj.data_od_przynaleznosci and cj.data_do_przynaleznosci))
            OR
            (@wstawiany_czlonek = cj.id_uzytkownika AND (@wstawiany_koniec between cj.data_od_przynaleznosci and cj.data_do_przynaleznosci))
            OR
            (@wstawiany_czlonek = cj.id_uzytkownika AND (@wstawiany_poczatek <= cj.data_od_przynaleznosci and @wstawiany_koniec >= cj.data_do_przynaleznosci))
            )
            AND cj.id_czlonkostwa <> @inserted_id_czlonkostwa
        )
    BEGIN
        raiserror('Wstawiany czlonek jest czlonkiem innej jednostki w tym samym czasie!',16,1)
        rollback
        return
    END
END
GO
```